# How to prevent default context menu on QGraphicsTextItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Is it possible to prevent right-click from opening the default context menu on `QGraphicsTextItem` ? The menu with "Undo, Redo, Cut, Copy, Paste..". On Ubuntu 18.04, that is. I don't know how this behaves on Windows.

I have overridden the mouse press handler to eat right-clicks in my view and tried to do that also in the item class itself. This actually did prevent the menu on Qt `5.10.0`, but for some reason not anymore on `5.11.1`:

[image]

```
void EditorView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{ 
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    ...
    doOtherHandlingStuff();
    ...
}
```

In the item itself it doesn't have any effect if I do this:

```
void TextEdit::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
{
    event->ignore();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the contextMenuEvent method of QGraphicsTextItem:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class GraphicsTextItem: public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    using QGraphicsTextItem::QGraphicsTextItem;
protected:
    void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event) override
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView w{&scene};
    auto it = new GraphicsTextItem("Hello World");
    it->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditable);
    scene.addItem(it);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```